# Saving Split Layer segments to separate Shape files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers

I might be missing something obvious here.  Using the Split Features tool I've split a line feature into 2 parts, one of which is now showing as being selected (yellow highlight).

How do I save each part to a new Shapefile?

Comment: Should have said "feature" instead of "layer".

Comment: Please edit your question

Comment: Split Layer tool, do you mean the Spit Features tool on the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar?  If the feature in the map is selected and edits saved right click the layer in the layer panel and select Save As option and save only selected features to shapefile.

Comment: right-click on layer -> save as... -> checkbox 'selected features only'; then, invert selection via select menu -> repeat ?